# State change is resetting navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using Firestore with a React Native app. I am getting initial data and listening for changes in realtime from `App.js`. My React Navigation code is also located on `App.js`. I need to pass the data from Firestore to two components, `Details` and `Countdown`. These components are in different navigation stacks. When an update to Firestore is made from `Details`, a state update happens on `App.js`, forcing the user back to the home screen.

How can I prevent this from happening?

**App.js**

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [countdownGames, setCountdownGames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        setUser(user);
      }
    });
    return subscriber;
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const gameSubscription = firestore().collection("games").where("owner", "==", user.uid).onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      let tempMedia = []
      querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
        tempMedia.push(doc.data());
      });
      // State change here is forcing user back to home page
      setCountdownGames(tempMedia);
    }, error => console.log(error));
    return () => {
      gameSubscription();
    };
  }, [user]);

  const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
  function HomeStackScreen() {
    return <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Find" component={Search} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Details" component={Details} initialParams={{ uid: user?.uid, games: countdownGames }} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  }

  const CountdownStack = createStackNavigator();
  function CountdownStackScreen() {
    return <CountdownStack.Navigator>
      <CountdownStack.Screen name="Countdown" component={Countdown} initialParams={{ uid: user?.uid, games: countdownGames }} />
    </CountdownStack.Navigator>
  }

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  function TabNavigation() {
    return <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Find" component={HomeStackScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Countdown" component={CountdownStackScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  }

  const Stack = createStackNavigator();
  return <NavigationContainer>
    <StatusBar />
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={TabNavigation} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
}
```

Comment: First option, I would advise you for useDeepCompareEffect(https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect) instead of useEffect since user is an object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're creating React components inside React components. You should never do that. Define all your components at top level of the file.

Instead of:

```js
export default function App() {
  // Whatever

  const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
  function HomeStackScreen() {
    // Whatever
  }
}
```

Do:

```js
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStackScreen() {
  // Whatever
}

export default function App() {
  // Whatever
}
```

More info https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#screens-are-unmountingremounting-during-navigation